# Unity - Get new coordinates using old coordinates and line length between them

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game where the player-object is running in a circle around origin. I want the player to be able to make the circle bigger or smaller. I have the distance between the new coordinates and origin and I have two old coordinates: current player coordinates and the origin. How do I get new coordinates aligned with the old coordinates and the origin using line lenght?

I am using unity and c#.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see what you already have? This makes the process easier.

Maybe [Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) Could help you?

You only have to update the position of the player to "make the circle bigger". For example:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 target = new Vector3(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    void Update()
    {
        // Spin the object around the world origin around the Yaxis 20 degrees/second.
        transform.RotateAround(target, Vector3.up, 30 * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    Public void IncreaseDistance(float amount){
        //you need a vector in de direction you want to move to. You get this by
        // calculating the distance vector from the target to this.gameObject. Then normalize it

       Vector3 direction = (transform.position - target).normalize; //to - from;
       transform.position += direction * amount
    }
}
```